# Removing appended forward slash from URL in Ember.js when using link-to

Tags: javascript, url, ember.js, link-to

I am new to ember and am liking it so far but I am hoping someone can help me with the URLs in my site.

I can load a template in ember using a url that looks something like this:

```
www.test.com/#home
```

and it will load up the home template, no problem.

But if I use a link-to home from inside the site, the URL will look like this:

```
www.test.com/#/home
```

I want the links to always look like the first example.

Any ideas?

Comment: The second example—the one you don't want—looks correct to me. The first one ('www.test.com/#home') looks wrong. I would expect that url to represent the open state of a tab on the page or something. That said, I do not know the answer to your question, but I suspect you will need to study the implementations of hash-based and location-based routing in the ember source code.

Comment: Actually, you could replace the current state of window.history by observing 'currentPath'. This might cause tons of bugs though. Not sure.

Comment: I appreciate the comments.  I have attempted to control the window history myself in this same web application before I migrated to ember and it was a nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

Give href as "#/home"

`<a class="ember-view selected" href="#/home">Home</a>`

Refer this http://todomvc.com/examples/emberjs/
ember Demo TODO